# RunTimeException in running timerTask in android

Tags: android, timer, task, runtimeexception

In my android service I am running a simple timer but android throws exception...

My code as follows

```
public class MyService extends Service{
   private Timer timer = new Timer();

   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
        func1();
        }
        }, 0, UPDATE_INTERVAL);

   }
}


void func1(){
    Log.i(TAG,"Just printing");
}
```

But my code throws exception like this

```
09-30 11:56:54.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-30 11:56:54.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
09-30 11:56:54.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.<init>(LocationManager.java:173)
09-30 11:56:54.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.<init>(LocationManager.java:173)
09-30 11:56:54.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:579)
09-30 11:56:54.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:446)
09-30 11:56:54.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at com.example.mobiletracker.MTrackerService.func1(MTrackerService.java:167)
09-30 11:56:54.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at com.example.mobiletracker.MTrackerService$4.run(MTrackerService.java:118)
09-30 11:56:54.297: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Can anybody please provide me any solution ?

Comment: I tried this code i did not get any exception..once check where u used LocationManager class. or post related code